# Group data by date

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, transpose

How can I take a list of data and group them by date?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this, here are few possible ways:

Using `UNIQUE()`, `TOROW()` & `FILTER()` function:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A21)
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=TOROW(FILTER(B$2:B$21,D2=A$2:A$21))
```

---

Or, Dynamically spill using one single formula:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _data, A2:B21,
     _date, TAKE(_data,,1),
     _udate, UNIQUE(_date),
     _rows, ROWS(_udate),
     _columns, MAX(COUNTIFS(_date,_date)),
     _databody, MAKEARRAY(_rows,_columns,LAMBDA(r,c, INDEX(FILTER(DROP(_data,,1),_date=INDEX(_udate,r),""),c))),
     VSTACK(HSTACK(A1,B1&"_"&SEQUENCE(,_columns)),HSTACK(_udate,IFERROR(_databody,""))))
```

---

Or, Using `REDUCE()`

```
=LET(
     _Date, A2:A21,
     _Desk, B2:B21,
     _Udate, UNIQUE(_Date),
     _Headers, HSTACK(A1,B1&"_"&SEQUENCE(,MAX(COUNTIFS(A2:A21,A2:A21)))),
     IFERROR(REDUCE(_Headers,_Udate,LAMBDA(r,c,VSTACK(r, HSTACK(c,TOROW(FILTER(B2:B21,A2:A21=c,"")))))),""))
```

---

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    GroupByDate = Table.Group(Source, {"Date"}, {{"Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),type table}}),
    ExpandingData = Table.ExpandTableColumn(GroupByDate, "Custom", {"Desk", "Index"}, {"Desk", "Index"}),
    Formatting = Table.TransformColumns(ExpandingData, {{"Index", each "Desk " & Text.From(_, "en-US"), type text}}),
    PivotColumns = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Formatting, {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Formatting, {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US")[Index]), "Index", "Desk"),
    DataTypeChanged = Table.TransformColumnTypes(PivotColumns,{{"Date", type date}, {"Desk 1", type text}, {"Desk 2", type text}, {"Desk 3", type text}, {"Desk 4", type text}, {"Desk 5", type text}, {"Desk 6", type text}, {"Desk 7", type text}})
in
    DataTypeChanged
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---